# Is it possible to launch multiple nodes from different packages in ROS2 (Crystal)?

Tags: ros, launch, ros2

I have 5 ros2 packages and each package contains one or two nodes. Is it possible to launch all nodes from different packages at once? If possible how I can do it? are there any git repo with examples for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read the [tutorials](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Launch-system/) which leads to this sample launch configuration: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/launch/services/add_two_ints.launch.py